# How to normalize the output signal after matched filtering to the level of input signal?

Tags: filter, signal-processing

### What I want

Suppose I have the input signal(Raw data) in the figure and I want to pass it through a matched filter. The ideal output is like that in the figure(Filtered data) where the filtered data is at the same level as raw data.
[image: Matched filter \label{fig1}]

### What I get

I used `scipy.signal.lfilter()` to implement the matched filter. The main code is as follow:

```py
# Template function
def template(t, a=1, tau=0.02, c=0, t0=0):
    return a * np.exp(-(t - t0) / tau) + c

# Template signal
t = np.arange(0, 0.05, 1e-4)
signal = template(t)

# matched filter
# raw_without_dc: remove dc component from raw data, implemented as substracting mean value of raw datas
mf = sp.lfilter(signal[::-1], 1, raw_without_dc)**2 

# Plot filtered datas
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
plt.plot(times/1e6, raw_data, alpha=0.5, label='Raw data')
plt.plot(times[:-500]/1e6, mf[500:], color='r',label='Filtered data')
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.legend()
```

The plotted raw data and filtered data are as follow:
[image: Raw data]
[image: My filtered data]

### Question

**Is there any formal method I can use to normalize the output signal after matched filtering to the level of input signal?**

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?